# Xamarin.Forms. XAML Label IsVisible condition is not getting evaluated as expected

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my project I have to select several options on a page.

Every option has a type `MyCustomType` and has public string `Name` property declared.

Every option is displayed via label. When I click on the label I display list of options and select it.

As one option is selected, an empty label with placeholder text (like `select an item`) for another option should appear below the label with the just selected option.

I use separate labels for every option, not a ListView element (customer's requirement for the particular look & feel).

Number of options is limited, let say it equals to four.

In my viewmodel I have declared the list property (it has been initialized in viewmodel constructor):

```
public List<MyCustomType> AllOptions { get; }
```

In my XAML page labels are declared as:

```
<Label Text="{Binding AllOptions[0].Name}" >

<Label Text="{Binding AllOptions[1].Name}" IsVisible="{Binding AllOptions[0], Converter={StaticResource NullToFalseBoolConverter}}">

<Label Text="{Binding AllOptions[2].Name}" IsVisible="{Binding AllOptions[1], Converter={StaticResource NullToFalseBoolConverter}}">

<Label Text="{Binding AllOptions[3].Name}" IsVisible="{Binding AllOptions[2], Converter={StaticResource NullToFalseBoolConverter}}">
```

Converter `NullToFalseBoolConverter` looks like that:

```
public class NullToFalseBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The problem is that IsVisible condition, specified into label declarations does not work.

All labels are displayed.

And breakpoint, set to the first line of `Convert` method of `NullToFalseBoolConverter` is not getting reached.

I don't understand why does it happen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to use ObservableCollection instead of List?. And your "MyCustomType" imeplements INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Are you seeing any binding errors in the output window during debug?  Sometimes they are hard to notice.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I've copied all text output to the notepad and searched by `exception` and `error` words. No error nor exception has occurred.

Comment: @JorgeFernandezHerrero yes, I've also tried ObservableCollection. `MyCustomType` is a pure data model type. It holds only string value, and this value does not change at runtime. Why should I implement INotifyPropertyChanged for `MyCustomType` in this case?

Comment: When I try to recreate this locally, I get the build error `'IsVisible' property is read-only and cannot be set from markup.`.  Should you be using the `Visibility` property, with a converter that converts `null` to `Hidden` instead?

Comment: @JorgeFernandezHerrero I've found the solution, please check if you are interested.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I've found the solution, please check if you are interested.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I did not understand you comment. I use `IsVisible` property for `Label` XAML element. It can be set in the way I have described and it works now, as I described in my answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying binding in that matter, consider using either a layout type that supports both an ItemSource and also a data template. So this would be something like a ListView/CollectionView/Stacklayout

So, for example, if you decide to use a StackLayout for example:

```
<StackLayout
...
BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding AllOptions}">
<BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" IsVisible="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource NullToFalseBoolConverter}}">

        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

The beauty of this approach is that since your labels all follow the same approach you can now not only A) write cleaner code, and B) leverage MVVM patterns. Now, of course this does mean that each control gets the converters applied to them as well; however, if still want to not include it for the first element then all we have to do is change your type to include an index property. If you're wondering what the syntax `Binding .` means, it means that we are just binding the whole object of that collection for that element.

`public int Index {get; set;}`

Set it where you build that array, and then in the converter all you have to do is:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
var element = (MyCustomType) value;
if(element.Index != 0)
        return value != null;
else
        return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

So as an addition to what you want to do in terms of passing the selected item to your command you can do the following. I am assuming that your overall page is a , but the same concept applies to any type of page really.

1. Set an `x:Name` property on the , give it any name you want. ex:

   <ContentPage
   ...
   x:Name="root">
2. Define a `<GestureRecognizer>` on your Label

`<Label Text="{Binding Name}" IsVisible="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource NullToFalseBoolConverter}}"> <Label.GestureRecognizers> <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.YourCommandName, Source={x:Reference root}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/> </Label.GestureRecognizers>`

3. In your view model that is bond to the page, create the following command as follows:

   public ICommand YourCommandName => new Command(x =>
   YourCustomMethodHere(x));
4. Finally create the method that handles the object you selected

   public void YourCustomMethodHere(MyCustomType type) {}

So what the above XAML code does is that we are binding the command of the Label to the overall parent view model, when an item is inside of a DataTemplate that has been defined by its ItemSource, its view model is actually the model that is being used a data template; that is why we are setting its source VM to be the one for the overall parent. The `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"` is the same logic as before, we are binding that whole data template item, in this case the `MyCustomType` that has been rendered for that element. This way each time that label is tapped, we are passing that label and its data to the command that we now defined in the VM.

Comment: thank you for such detailed answer. I will check this approach later and if it works I will accept your answer as solution. Thank you again.

Comment: My real task is more complex than I pictured on my question, there is a condition to display the first item, not based on index. And upon clicking on a label I am calling a command, and passing a label index to this command, to put the selected value to the relevant label. Anyway I am going to accept your answer as solution for my particular question I have asked. I like it. Thank you.

Comment: @Rafael I've made an edit to my answer that can help address your need, I hope I understood your situation correctly.

Answer (score 1):

That's funny, but the following approach fixed my problem.

I've had `AllOptions` declared as `List` (did not work), and as `ObservableCollection` (did not work too).

I should declare my list as **array**:

```
public MyCustomType[] AllOptions { get; }
```

And my labels start displaying properly, one after another is set.

And upon processing its values, if I get null value, that means, that we're reached the end of populated options.

Comment: Odds are that since you are trying to access them view an index is why the array worked